# error while trying to get cordova plugins using phonegap

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

i'm new with phonegap so i really need some help.

I try to run index.html and use phonegap but i get error while trying to get cordova plugins.

my config.xml:

```
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" id="com.phonegap.helloworld" version="1.0.0">
  <name>project</name>
  <description>Hello World sample application that responds to the deviceready event.</description>
  <author href="http://phonegap.com" email="support@phonegap.com">PhoneGap Team</author>
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-battery-status" source="npm" spec="~1.1.1"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" source="npm" spec="~2.1.1"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-media-capture" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" source="npm" spec="~1.0.2"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-contacts" source="npm" spec="~2.0.1"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" source="npm" spec="~1.1.1"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-motion" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-orientation" source="npm" spec="~1.0.2"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" source="npm" spec="~4.1.1"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" source="npm" spec="~1.5.0"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" source="npm" spec="~2.1.0"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-globalization" source="npm" spec="~1.0.3"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" source="npm" spec="~1.3.0"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-media" source="npm" spec="~2.2.0"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source="npm" spec="~3.2.1"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" source="npm" spec="~2.1.2"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-vibration" source="npm" spec="~2.1.0"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" spec="~1.2.1"/>
  <icon src="icon.png"/>
  <platform name="android">
    <icon src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" density="ldpi"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" density="mdpi"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" density="hdpi"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" density="xhdpi"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxhdpi"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" density="land-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" density="land-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" density="land-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xxxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxxhdpi"/>
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon.png" platform="ios" width="57" height="57"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon@2x.png" platform="ios" width="114" height="114"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-40.png" platform="ios" width="40" height="40"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-40@2x.png" platform="ios" width="80" height="80"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-50.png" platform="ios" width="50" height="50"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-50@2x.png" platform="ios" width="100" height="100"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-60.png" platform="ios" width="60" height="60"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-60@2x.png" platform="ios" width="120" height="120"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-60@3x.png" platform="ios" width="180" height="180"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" platform="ios" width="72" height="72"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72@2x.png" platform="ios" width="144" height="144"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-76.png" platform="ios" width="76" height="76"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-76@2x.png" platform="ios" width="152" height="152"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-small.png" platform="ios" width="29" height="29"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-small@2x.png" platform="ios" width="58" height="58"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-small@3x.png" platform="ios" width="87" height="87"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" platform="ios" width="640" height="1136"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-667h.png" platform="ios" width="750" height="1334"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-736h.png" platform="ios" width="1242" height="2208"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape-736h.png" platform="ios" width="2208" height="1242"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" platform="ios" width="2048" height="1536"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" platform="ios" width="1024" height="768"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" platform="ios" width="1536" height="2048"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" platform="ios" width="768" height="1024"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/ios/Default@2x~iphone.png" platform="ios" width="640" height="960"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/ios/Default~iphone.png" platform="ios" width="320" height="480"/>
  </platform>
  <platform name="wp8">
    <icon src="www/res/icon/wp8/ApplicationIcon.png" platform="wp8" width="99" height="99"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/wp8/Background.png" platform="wp8" width="159" height="159"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/wp8/screen-portrait.jpg" platform="wp8" width="768" height="1280"/>
  </platform>
  <platform name="windows">
    <icon src="www/res/icon/windows/Square150x150Logo.scale-100.png" platform="windows" width="150" height="150"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/windows/Square30x30Logo.scale-100.png" platform="windows" width="30" height="30"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/windows/StoreLogo.scale-100.png" platform="windows" width="50" height="50"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/windows/SplashScreen.scale-100.png" platform="windows" width="620" height="300"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/windows/StoreLogo.scale-240.png" platform="windows" width="120" height="120"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/windows/Square44x44Logo.scale-100.png" platform="windows" width="44" height="44"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/windows/Square44x44Logo.scale-240.png" platform="windows" width="106" height="106"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/windows/Square70x70Logo.scale-100.png" platform="windows" width="70" height="70"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/windows/Square71x71Logo.scale-100.png" platform="windows" width="71" height="71"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/windows/Square71x71Logo.scale-240.png" platform="windows" width="170" height="170"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/windows/Square150x150Logo.scale-240.png" platform="windows" width="360" height="360"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/windows/Square310x310Logo.scale-100.png" platform="windows" width="310" height="310"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/windows/Wide310x150Logo.scale-100.png" platform="windows" width="310" height="150"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/windows/Wide310x150Logo.scale-240.png" platform="windows" width="744" height="360"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/windows/SplashScreenPhone.scale-240.png" platform="windows" width="1152" height="1920"/>
  </platform>
  <access origin="*"/>
  <allow-intent href="http://*/*"/>
  <allow-intent href="https://*/*"/>
  <allow-intent href="tel:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="sms:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="mailto:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="geo:*"/>
  <platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*"/>
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*"/>
  </platform>
</widget>
```

my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
    Copyright (c) 2012-2016 Adobe Systems Incorporated. All rights reserved.

    Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
    or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
    distributed with this work for additional information
    regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
    to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
    "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
    with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
    software distributed under the License is distributed on an
    "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
     KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
    specific language governing permissions and limitations
    under the License.
-->
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=10, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width" />
    <!-- This is a wide open CSP declaration. To lock this down for production, see below. -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *" />
    <!-- Good default declaration:
    * gap: is required only on iOS (when using UIWebView) and is needed for JS->native communication
    * https://ssl.gstatic.com is required only on Android and is needed for TalkBack to function properly
    * Disables use of eval() and inline scripts in order to mitigate risk of XSS vulnerabilities. To change this:
        * Enable inline JS: add 'unsafe-inline' to default-src
        * Enable eval(): add 'unsafe-eval' to default-src
    * Create your own at http://cspisawesome.com
    -->
    <!-- <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: 'unsafe-inline' https://ssl.gstatic.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *" /> -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="width:100%;height:30px;top:10px;position:relative;background-color:#000;">
        <ul style="list-style:none;padding:5px;"> 
            <li style="float:left;">
                <a href="Menu.html">Menu</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="app">
        <div style="top:10px;position:relative;">
            <ul>
                <li>Test 1</li>
                <li>Test 2</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <h1>Hello PhoneGap</h1>
        <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
            <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
            <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
        </div>

    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/functions.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

my index.js:

```
    /*
 * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
 * or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
 * distributed with this work for additional information
 * regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
 * to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
 * "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
 * with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
 * software distributed under the License is distributed on an
 * "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
 * KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
 * specific language governing permissions and limitations
 * under the License.
 */
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);

    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    }
};
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What error do you get ?

Comment: I don't know because i can't see the console in the iphone, but i know that the request is starting but never complete and the server don't get the request, thank you!